# Visualize Tree Structure

Tags: c, tree

I try to debug my program which uses a tree structure to search particles. I want to do a visual proof if the tree structure looks correctly. Therefore I want to draw the tree structure (only for small trees) in the console.

I do the following to do a post-order walk trough the tree structure.

```
void treeWalk(TreeNode *t, int level){
    if(t != NULL){
        for(int i=0; i<POWDIM; i++){
            if(t->son[i] != NULL){

                printf("down to son %d level %d)\n", i, level);

                treeWalk(t->son[i], level+1);
            }
        }
        // Operation on *t
        if(isLeaf(t) == TRUE)
            print("son is a leaf\n");
        else
            print("son is a node"); 
        // End of operation on *t
    }
}
```

Where `isLeaf(t)` is a function to distinguish a particle (leaf) from a node without a particle. `TreeNode` is a structure defined as:

```
typedef struct TreeNode{
    Particle p;
    struct TreeNode *son[DIM*DIM];
}
```

Where `DIM` is 2 or 3.

Is there an easy way to print such a tree structure to the console? I imagine something like:

```
        0
       / \
      /   \
     0     0
    / \   / \
   x   x x   x
```

Comment: @squeamishossifrage In my case I am working with quadtrees and octrees.

Comment: Oh, ok. But I'm afraid your question is still off-topic: *["Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)*

Comment: @Samuel: To verify tree and graph structures, I recommend the program outputs the structures using the Graphviz DOT format (it's a very simple text format); then, one can use e.g. `dot` or `neato` etc. to view the structures. It is much easier, works for bigger trees, and you can even include some interesting cases (by saving the images created by the Graphviz tools) in your project folder. But, using DOT to describe a tree (or a graph) is a completely different question to doing the same by printing the tree to console using ASCII graphics.